# Convert date to ticks in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Does anyone know how to convert a DATETIME COLUMN to TICKS in SQL Server?

Comment: Why not do it in .NET code (where it is easy)?

Comment: Because I have some records in the database and I need to convert them with one single query from MSSQL

Comment: Can you give us some more details about why you need to do this conversion in SQL Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to have t-sql convert a value to ticks that can be compared with the "same" value created in .NET it will not work. A DateTime data type in SQL Server only has a precision of about .003 seconds (actually values are rounded to .000, .003 or .007) or 10<sup>-3</sup> whereas a DateTime data type in .NET has a precision of 100 nanoseconds (10<sup>-7</sup>).

Comment: datetime2 in SQL Server 2008 does fix this somewhat

Comment: @gbn - Not really. If you stored the values from .NET into a DateTime2(7), then because of the additional precision, you can get a 1:1 match. But I'm not really sure how you can calculate an equivalent Ticks value off a DateTime2(7) given the limitations of DateDiff.

Comment: @gbn - Actually, in futzing around with it, there is a way to calculate the ticks off a DateTime2(7) to get the equivalent of .NET's Ticks property. It is a bit convoluted since you can't use DateDiff but it is possible.