# T-sql, ticks, timestamp

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get something C# like DateTime.Ticks in t-sql ?

thanks for help

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892447/convert-date-to-ticks-in-sql-server

Answer (score 10):

It's unlikely you'll be able to get the same kind of accuracy out of SQL as DateTime.Ticks since SQL doesn't express time in that much precision. SQL Server only stores time to approximately 1/300th of a second, whereas a single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
```

The above query will get you a Unix-style timestamp if that works, but to make any real suggestions I'd need to know what you're using the data for. If you need higher resolution than 3 ms though, you need to look outside of SQL.

```
               DATETIME: 0.01      (3 ms)
QueryPerformanceCounter: 0.0000001 (100 ns)
              DATETIME2: 0.0000001 (7 decimal places, 100 ns)
```

Comment: Since this answer was posted, a new data type `DATETIME2` was introduced with more precision

Answer (score 4):

There is no special type like in C#.NET
 But you can 
1) write .net procedure 
or 
2) use such code (please compare with .net):

```
declare @dt datetime; 
set @dt = getutcdate()

declare      @Ticks BIGINT

set @ticks = 
     cast(639905 + datediff(day,'1/1/1753',@dt) as bigint)*864000000000
    +
    cast(datediff(ms,datediff(day,0,@dt) ,@dt) as bigint)*10000

      DECLARE @Days  BIGINT
      DECLARE @DaysBefore1753 BIGINT
      DECLARE @TimeTicks BIGINT
      DECLARE @mSeconds BIGINT

      SET @Days = @Ticks / CONVERT(BIGINT,864000000000)
      SET @DaysBefore1753 = CONVERT(BIGINT,639905)
      SET @TimeTicks = @Ticks % CONVERT(BIGINT,864000000000)
      SET @mSeconds = @TimeTicks / CONVERT(BIGINT,10000)


      select @dt, @ticks, DATEADD(ms,@mSeconds,DATEADD(d,@Days - @DaysBefore1753,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/1/1753')))
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what 639905 and 10000 refer to in this instance? This works great for me, but I just want to understand why these numbers are being used. I get that 86400... refers to ticks per day.

Comment: 639905 obvously - days from 0000-01-01 till 1753. 10000 - good magic value from Copperfield (top secret):). 86400 - seconds per day.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL Server 2008? This might help.

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/danny/archive/2008/01/10/sql-server-2008-time-data-type.aspx