# Converting Date to ticks in c# (for table storage queries)

Tags: c#, date, azure, azure-table-storage

i have a table storage where the partition key is the DateTime ticks generated every second.

I want to retrieve records from a certain date by querying the partition keys that were generated at that time.

i think i need a way where i supply a date and convert it to ticks. or is there a better approach for the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need the `.Ticks` property on a datetime:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

Without really grepping your data structure, you may need some sort of between query to get all the records you need, possibly supplying two dates.

Note that if the ticks key isn't generated via C#, then you may need to use whatever mechanism is generating the ticks to get a key at the same level of accuracy, see below link for t-sql example:

[T-sql, ticks, timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080127/t-sql-ticks-timestamp)

Answer (score 3):

There's actually more to it than simply using .Ticks. I blogged about this a while ago: [NuGet package for creating and querying Table Storage entities in (reverse) chronological order](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/nuget-package-for-storing-table-storage-entities-in-reverse-chronological-order/). The NuGet package (which supports both the old and new Table Storage SDK) allows you to create entities based on the current time and also allows you to query them (even supports date ranges).

**Creating entities** (look at `RowKey.CreateChronological`)

```
foreach (var blogPost in BlogReader.Read())
{
    table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(new Model.BlogPostEntity()
    {
        Author = blogPost.Author,
        PartitionKey = "WindowsAzure",
        PublishedOn = blogPost.PublishedOn,
        Title = blogPost.Title,
        RowKey = RowKey.CreateChronological(blogPost.PublishedOn)
    }));
}
```

**Query entities** (look at `QueryDateReverseChronologicalComparisons.After`)

```
var ctx = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices.TableServiceContext(table.ServiceClient);
var query = ctx.CreateQuery<BlogPostTableServiceEntity>("ChronoTableStorageSample")
               .Where(QueryDateReverseChronologicalComparisons.After, 
                        DateTime.Parse("2012-12-10 00:00:00"));

foreach (var blogPost in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}: {1}", blogPost.PublishedOn, blogPost.Title);
}
```