# Generate field in MySQL SELECT with random value

Tags: sql

I need to export data from a database with a new random field not present in the database.
Something like:

```
SELECT field1, field2, rand(1,5) as field3 FROM table
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `RAND()` returns a value between 0 and 1.  Use math to make that number be within the range you want.

[MySQL RAND Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Answer (score 0):

Not a MySQL answer, but may be of use: on SQL Server the 'RAND' function requires a seed that must differ between rows. Therefore a simple way may be:

```
SELECT field1, field2, rand(id) as field3 FROM table
```

This is dependant upon an ID being available, and it is also only pseudo-random; the same value for field3 will be output each time. To work around this, simply increment id by a time-based value, for example using the technique in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080127/t-sql-ticks-timestamp):

```
SELECT field1, field2, rand(id + datediff(s, '19700101', getdate())) as field3 FROM table
```

This will give a value between 0 and 1, and a bit of simple mathematics can then force that to be between 1 and 5 if that's what's required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in MYSQL:-

```
SELECT field1,field2,CAST((RAND() * 3) + 1 AS UNSIGNED) as Randomnumber from tablename
```

It will generate a random number within  a range.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

CEIL( RAND( ) *5 ) AS field3

Thank you all!