# Ticks in sql for 01/01/1901 00:00:00

Tags: sql

I am try to use a redgate product that needs the date in ticks i.e 634925952000000000 = 01/01/2013 00:00:00

Can I find a convertor to work out 01/01/1901 00:00:00 in sql

without this happening "The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '19010101', GETDATE())*1000000
```

answer no can anyone help.

Just the the value for 01/01/1901 00:00:00 really as app use this as a null date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of seconds returned between those 2 dates is too many for the datediff data type to support which is an int.  I've seen others use the difference in minutes, then convert to seconds using BigInt instead.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'19010101',getDate()) * CONVERT(BIGINT,60)
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8008).

Good luck.

Comment: the OP want this result `01/01/1901 00:00:00` :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY the below query... may be it helps you...

```
DECLARE @date datetime
DECLARE @ticksperday bigint
set @date = getdate()
set @ticksPerDay = 864000000000
declare @date2 datetime2 = getdate()
declare @dateBinary binary(9) = cast(reverse(cast(@date2 as binary(9))) as binary(9))
declare @days bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 1, 3) as bigint)
declare @time bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 4, 5) as bigint)

select @date as [DateTime], @date2 as [DateTime2], @days * @ticksPerDay + @time as [Ticks]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [datetimeconversion](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, datetick, 120) FROM supportContacts
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf12a/21)

Comment: Spajce, I need the tick value the comes out 1901-01-01

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892447/convert-date-to-ticks-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

599581440000000000 is the value fro some reason none of the above solutions came up with this.